# Rails - separate front end and back end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, structure

I'm building a Rails application where all the front end files are store in a different server from the Rails server. Thus all requests are handled by AJAX sent by Javascript.

I did this partially for separating the front end and back end and to prevent getting the app messy. And since I was using Google Closure Library, but Rails doesn't seem to support it very well.

What I wonder is that whether it is generally a good practice, or is it really necessary to do this. Now I have problems with CSRF, that I could not figure out how to safely send AJAX to the server since I have no access to the csrf token at the front end without breaking my session.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that if you're using a solid back-end with proper API support, then you don't have a problem.

This article on API servers on Rails:
http://broadcastingadam.com/2012/03/state_of_rails_apis/

shows there are a number of implementations out there and various works in progress. API versioning appears to be one problematic area.

And if you're concerned about CSRF, I would recommend looking at [rack_csrf](https://github.com/baldowl/rack_csrf).